# Angular velocity when an object splits into two parts

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Let us say we have a cylinder rolling with an angular velocity **'w'**. Now it splits into two parts of the same radius from middle without the application of any external torque. So how do I determine the angular velocity of the two parts?

Comment: Total angular momentum is conserved

Answer (score 1):

Angular velocity is the same everywhere in a rigid body.  There may be linear velocities and accelerations that vary from point to point to maintain the rigid body assumptions, but the angular velocity is the same everywhere.

So thus, at the moment after the split but before any internal forces are applied, you can assume the angular velocity for both parts is the same as it was before, and compute the correct linear velocity at the center of mass for both parts.

At that point, we need to ask "how" your object splits.  You mention there's no external torque, but in this case internal torques will matter.  Based on the exact separation mechanics you choose for your object, more or less torques may be applied to your halves.  If you use a force to push them apart which goes directly through the centers of mass of both halves, then that won't introduce any torque.  However, if that force is not perfectly in line, it will induce a torque in one direction on one half, and an opposite torque on the other.

If you cannot afford a force to separate your objects, nature will provide one for you.  If your object merely cracks in half with no intentional force pushing the halves apart, the rotation will naturally cause one half to try to intersect with the other.  This will cause a force that drives them apart.  For most fracture lines, this will not be in-line with the centers of mass, so you will impart a torque on both halves.

As Bob D points out in the comments, no matter what forces are involved, you can at least assume that momentum is conserved.  This restricts how many ways the objects can split, but the specifics are left up to the mechanism.

Comment: So both the halves still roll with 'w' angular velocity if the net torque is assumed to be zero?

Comment: @yyzr No. The total angular momentum will not change. That does not mean each piece must have the same angular velocity equal to the original angular velocity. Just like how in a linear collision the momentum of each object can change while the total remains constant

Comment: Can you please calculate the angular momentum of each half, I can't understand how to calculate it

Comment: If "I" the moment of inertia of the initial cylinder, L= Iw, the moment of inertia of the new halves become "I/2", L1=(I/2)*(w1), where w1 is the new angular velocity. So, Iw = 2*(I/2)*w1. On solving I get w=w1. Where am I wrong

Comment: @yyzr That is correct.  Without accounting for any interactions between the two halves, thinking of a rigid body as two bodies rather than one doesnt' change the physics -- it still is rotating with the same angular velocity.  The object doesn't change just because we think of it differently (one piece or two).  The interesting step is the next step, when you account for *how* they separate.  The internal reactions will matter.  Different ways of breaking up will lead to different distributions of angular momentum between the halves.

Comment: This was in my test today and my friends are telling that the angular velocity becomes '2w', what they are doing is equating L1 and L